# JQuery: How to select table rows but not the rows of the table inside the cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a table, and there are tables within the cell too, like this:

```
<table id='table1'>
   <tr>
       <td>xyz</td>
       <td>
           <table><tr></tr></table>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```

How do I use jquery to select those  only directly under "table1", but not those  under the inside table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$('#table1').children('tr')
```

or [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('#table1 > tr')
```

These will select only direct children elements

as @jonathanlonowski stated, it would be safer to use this due to the browsers adding the extra `tbody` markup

```
$('#table1 > tr,#table1 > tbody > tr')
```

This would also work

```
$('#table1').find('tr:first').siblings().andSelf()
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but most (all?) browsers will add a `<tbody>` when one wasn't in the markup. So, the selector may need to be `$('#table1 > tbody > tr')`. http://jsfiddle.net/xdZcf/